# jQuery click event not firing immediately for drop down menu in google chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

jQuery v 1.7.1

Chrome v 18.0.1025.162

I have a jquery click event handler attached to a drop down menu. In FF/Safari the event handler fires immediately after the click, but I am observing weird behaviour in Chrome:

1. Click inside the drop down menu
2. Notice that the event handler has not fired (whereas it does in FF/Safari)
3. Tab to another application on computer while the drop down menu still has focus
4. Tab back to Chrome
5. Notice that the event handler has fired

Alternatively,

1. Click inside the drop down menu
2. Notice that the event handler has not fired
3. Click on another part of the page so that the drop down loses focus
4. Notice that the event handler has not fired
5. Tab to another application on computer
6. Tab back to Chrome
7. Notice that the event handler has not fired

```
    $("#dropdown-id").detectRealTimeChange(function(){
          $("#some-div").html("html content");
    );
    /**
     * Detect a change to an input without requiring the input to lose focus
     */
    jQuery.fn.detectRealTimeChange = function(callback){
        var oldValue = $(this).val();
        var didRecordChange = false;
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            var newValue = $(this).val();
            if(oldValue != newValue){
                if(!didRecordChange){
                    changeCount = changeCount + 1;
                    didRecordChange = true;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(didRecordChange){
                    changeCount = changeCount - 1;
                    didRecordChange = false;
                }
            }
            if(typeof callback == 'function'){
                callback.call(this);
            }
        });
        $(this).click(function(){
            var newValue = $(this).val();
            if(oldValue != newValue){
                if(!didRecordChange){
                    changeCount = changeCount + 1;
                    didRecordChange = true;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(didRecordChange){
                    changeCount = changeCount - 1;
                    didRecordChange = false;
                }
            }
            if(typeof callback == 'function'){
                callback.call(this);
            }
        });
```

Comment: do you  have any source code for that? or do you want us to guess?

Comment: They keyup event is fired in Chrome/FF/Safari, its just the click event that seems to not be fired